# How to install the bluejeans in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bluejeans

I want to install the bluejeans video conferencing in ubuntu laptop. I have tried but it showing the below error

> File "bluejeans-1.37.22.x86_64.rpm" not found

How can I find the RPM file name?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

1) Install gconf2:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

2) Install libappindicator1:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

In case you encounter an error: "Errors were encountered while processing:lvm2"
try this to fix lvm2:

```
sudo apt purge lvm2 && sudo apt install lvm2
```

3) Download BlueJeans from [here](https://www.bluejeans.com/downloads):

It will be a file named: BlueJeans.deb for Ubuntu

4) Install BlueJeans (open the Terminal in downloads folder):

```
sudo dpkg -i BlueJeans.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Sudo apt-get install alien`
2. Download the rpm from the bluejeans [website](https://www.bluejeans.com/downloads) and convert it with the following command.

`sudo alien --to-deb bluejeans-1.37.22.x86_64.rpm`

**replace the file with the downloaded rpm filename

3. 3.dpkg (Debian package) is a low-level tool. apt (advanced package tool) is a high-level tool, apt is more commonly used than dpkg as
   it can fetch packages from remote locations and can deal with
   complex package relations, such as dependency resolution, etc.
4. From the previous step deb file with the name
   "bluejeans_1.37.22-2_amd64.deb" was generated in my case. Now we will unpack the package and install it with the below command.

`sudo dpkg -i bluejeans_1.37.22-2_amd64.deb`

5. Start the blue jeans from below command

`/opt/bluejeans/bluejeans-bin`